# return an error from $http.success

Tags: angularjs, callback, promise

I am working in Angular and I need to signify an error to a promise further down the chain when the result is being resolved in .success().

I call a function in my service from my controller like

```
myService.myFunction().then(
   function(results){
      // do success stuff
   },
   function(err){
      // do failure stuff
   });
```

myFunction is something like

```
myFunction(){
    return $http.get('url')
       .success(function(results){})
       .error(function(err){})
}
```

Based on certain conditions, I need to have .then() execute the errorCallback even though $http.get().success() was triggered. How can I make it look like $http received an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some fixes that you need to do to achieve this would be use the `then` instead of `success` function on `$http`.

And in the `then` success callback you can do a `return $q.reject(errorData)` to reject the promise down the chain.

```
return $http.get('url').then(function(results){
    if(condition) {
      return $q.reject(errorData);
    }
    return result.data;  //then callback get a object with properties
},function(error) {
      return $q.reject(error);
  })
```

`success` returns the original `$http` promise whereas `then` returns a promise that gets resolved with the return value of success and error callback.

Comment: I think the problem is that my database was erroring out, but he server was still sending status code 200. Is the status code how Angular determines $http success or failure and can I achieve the same result by sending a failure status from the server?

Comment: Yes it is standard `http`. 2xx are all success. If the server returns 4xx or 5xx then you will go to error path.