# Angular promises: trigger catch(...) from within a then(...) statement?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Is it possible to trigger the `catch(...)` portion of a promise chain from within a `then(...)` portion?

For example, I make an $http request and chain some behavior. The $http resolves successfully, but upon processing of the data, it is clear the data is more suited for the error case, so we want to activate error handler instead.

The issue is -- I've got this promise chain being used within two locations; one is within the service itself, and the other is in the controller that activated the service. The controller is the one that handles the `catch(...)` portion of the promise chain, where it opens a modal that displays an error message.

So far, I've been able to chain the promise such that, whenever a `then(...)` or `catch(...)` is triggered within the service, I can return a result, and it will then be triggered within the controller -- just as expected.

But how do I have `then(...)` trigger within service, but return a result such that the `catch(...)` will be triggered instead within the controller?

I tried using `$q.reject(...)` to create and return a new promise, as the return value from within the `then(...)` function, but that didn't seem to work.

Example:

```
var url = 'http://google.com';
$http.get(url).then(handleFirst).then(handleSecond).catch(error);

function handleFirst (response) {
    console.log("HandleFirstCalled", response);
    return response;
}

function handleSecond (response) {
    console.log("HandleSecondCalled", response);
    return response;
}

function error (response) {
    console.log("ErrorCalled", response);
}
```

How do you get `handleFirst(...)`, skip executing `handleSecond(...)`, and execute `error(...)` instead? Note: you can't just call `error(response)` because there's no access to it from the outside promise chain.

**[Edit:]** Found the solution, `return $q.reject(response);` does work. However, the Service `catch(...)` function has to always `return $q.reject(response)`. Previously, I had it just `return response;`, which would be continued by the Controller promise chain. But then the Controller would activate `then(...)` within its chain.

So with `return response;` it went:

`Service -> $http -> then(...) -> catch(...) -> Controller -> then (...)`

By changing it `return $q.reject(response);` it goes:

`Service -> $http -> then(...) -> catch(...) -> Controller -> catch (...)`

Comment: You need to show some of your code. `return $q.reject(...)` should suffice

Comment: As @Phil said return $q.reject should work, i answered a similar question earlier today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924047/return-an-error-from-http-success/30924130#30924130

Comment: How about `$http.get(url).then(handleFirst).then(handleSecond, error)`?

Comment: @Phil @Chandermani Thanks, it does work. I was doing it wrong. Initially I did something like `var deferred = $q.deferred; deferred.reject(response); return deferred.promise;`. I didn't know you could use `$q.reject(...)` directly.

Comment: Hence why you should always use **actual code** in your questions if it's not working how you expect it to

Comment: Alternatively just `throw` an error in the `then` callback

Comment: @Phil Not always an option because of legal restrictions at the employer. But thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bergi I tried something like that too, but I couldn't get it working. You mean something like `return new throw Error(response);` or how?

Comment: @ngDeveloper at least the same control structures then. The code in your question doesn't mention `$q.defer` at all yet we find out in the comments that's what you're actually using.

Comment: @ngDeveloper: That's a syntax error. I mean `throw new Error(response);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options in Angular to reject the returned promise from within a then.

```
throw new Error(...); // this will reject the promise and trigger $exceptionHandler
```

Or:

```
return $q.reject(new Error(...)); // this will reject the promise
```

Use the first one to signal an error you can't really recover from and the latter for errors you can recover from.

Note that in standard (ES6 promises) and other compliant promises (like Bluebird) this distinction between throwing and rejecting isn't made.